# Power iteration provably works if the matrix has a unique eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $\lambda>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ real matrix and $v_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ s.t. $||v_0|| = 1$.  Define a sequence $(v_k)_k$ of $n$-dimensional real vectors by $v_k = A^kv_0 / || A^kv_0 ||$.  Assume that $A$ has a unique eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ and that $\lambda$ is real and positive. Under this assumption I would like to prove that $v_k$ converges as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

I believe that w.l.o.g. we may assume that $A$ is in the Jordan canonical form.  Moreover, to show the statement blockwise, we may assume $A$ is a Jordan block.  Then, we could write down the components of $v_k$ explicitly and show the convergence, although it would be quite messy.

My question is how to show the statement without getting too messy.  I would be grateful if you could give a clue (not necessarily a complete proof).

Comment: Dividing by $\|v\|$ does not allow separation of Jordan blocks. Therefore a simple counterexample is $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&c&-s\\0&s&c\end{pmatrix}$ where $c^2+s^2=1$, $s\neq 0$.

Comment: @ccorn:  your example has more than one eigenvalue.  In his question, Pteromys assumes $A$ has a unique eigenvalue.

Comment: @RobertLewis: Thanks, I thought in terms of "unique positive".

Comment: @ccorn I changed the title of the question so that its meaning would be clearer.

Comment: It could still be made more explicit that $\lambda$ is the unique _complex_ eigenvalue, which happens to be real (well, being unique it would _have_ to be real, but what I mean is that it is not just unique among the real eigenvalues). I know that most people will automatically assume that eigenvalues can be complex, even for a real linear map; it is just that the complex assumption is really essential here as the example by @ccorn shows.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, as you said $\lambda$ is meant to be unique in $\mathbb C$.  I clarified the description above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the normalisation done, the iteration used is unchanged when one multiplies $A$ by any positive real scalar; then by using the scalar $\lambda^{-1}$ one can therefore reduce the problem to the special case where $\lambda=1$. The fact that this is the unique complex eigenvalue means that $A=I+N$ for some nilpotent matrix$~N$. From the binomial formula and the fact that $N^n=0$ one gets $A^k\cdot v_0=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom ki N^i\cdot v_0$, and $v_k$ is that vector divided by its norm. Among the vectors $w_i=N^i\cdot v_0$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, let $w_l$ be the last one that is nonzero (which is well defined as $w_0=v_0\neq0$). Then one sees that $A^k\cdot v_0=k^l\frac{w_l}{l!}+O(k^{l-1})$. From this you should have no difficulty proving that $v_k$ converges to $w_l/\left\|w_l\right\|$.

Comment: And this does not require Jordan form. (+1)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I appreciate your concise answer.  This might be a silly question, but is the Landau's symbol often used for elements of normed vector spaces?  (I have not seen arguments like the one at the end very often and I am not familiar with it.)

Comment: I don't know about normed vector spaces in particular, but big-O and (even more) little-o are in general quite useful in showing that certain limits exist.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen why does the argument fail if $\lambda 0$?

Comment: @Pteromys: Scaling by $\lambda^{-1}$ is problematic for $\lambda=0$. Also you'd get $A^k\cdot v_0=0$ for $k=n$ (and maybe earlier), and $v_i$ wouldn't even be defined for $i\geq k$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I am sorry to bother you, but I intended to ask about the condition $\lambda < 0$ (and made a mistake in typing a LaTeX command).

Comment: The normalisation is not invariant under negative real scaling, so that is where $\lambda>0$ is used. You can see what does happen for $\lambda<0$ using either $A^k\cdot v_0=(-1)^k[(-A)^k\cdot v_0]$ where the part in square brackets converges by the argument for $\lambda>0$, or by using $(-I+N)^k\cdot v_0=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-i}\binom ki N^i\cdot v_0=(-1)^{k-l}k^l\frac{w_l}{l!}+O(k^{l-1})$. In any case you get a convergent sequence multiplied by alternating signs.